# Создание множественных состояний для телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу телеграмм бота (бот с тестами) на Python в aiogram и aiogram-dialog.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой при использовании aiogram-dialog.
Для смены экранов с кнопками нужны состояния, которые формируются в классе MyStates унаследованного от StatesGroup.
Количество вопросов в тестах и соответственно экранов разное поэтому вариант с жестко указанным количеством стэйтов работает, но не подходит:

Например 3 состояния:

```
class MyStates(StatesGroup):
    a = State()
    b = State()
    c = State()
```

```
state_list = [<State 'MyStates:a'>, <State 'MyStates:b'>, <State 'MyStates:c'>]
```

А у меня будет прилетать из БД какое-то количество вопросов и в теории проходя по циклу необходимо создать нужное количество состояний. Что-то вроде такого:

`lst = [State() for i in range(3)]` - получим список состояний, но это не работает - необходимо обязательно создать переменную и записать в нее State().
В данном случае получается список: `[<State ''>, <State ''>, <State ''>]`
и получаю ошибку:

```
raise RuntimeError('This state is not in any group.')
RuntimeError: This state is not in any group.
```

Вопрос: как создать нужное количество состояний пройдясь по циклу?

p.s.
Пробовал создавать в цикле строку (например 'state_1', 'state_2' и т.д.) через exec() преобразовывать строку в переменную и потом присваивать ей State(), но exec() как globals() и locals() не обрабатывает динамические переменные.

Comment: Ну так вам же так и написали, что стейт не может быть вне группы стетов

Comment: Я понимаю. Но как сделать множество стейтов проходя циклом?

Comment: Зачем? Вы же все равно не сможете использовать такой фильтр

Comment: К слову, вам же не обязательно делать исключительно через классы, можно сделать просто `state="prefix:staste_name"`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход с помощью функции **exec()** (до этого пробовал, но неправильно применил эту функцию).

```
class TestState(StatesGroup):
    states_list = [f'state_{i}=State()'for i in range(10)]
    for state in states_list:
        exec(state)
```

Таким образом вытягивая из БД количество вопросов в тесте и передав его вместо range() - получаю необходимое количество объектов State().